# Hide the ASPxPopupControl from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have added an ASPxPopupControl, which includes a Save Button, and I want to close it after saving a record.

I tried the following:

```
 string str = @"<script language=""javascript"" type=""text/javascript"">function HideEscalateAsk() {pcEscalteAsk.Hide();}</script>";
                   Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ClientScript", str);
```

but it still doesn't work. How can I close the ASPxPopupControl?

Comment: care to add correct tag.. if it is regarding devexpress control then add `devexpress` tag also..    try to put this client script code on page and then call client side click event of save button.. what ever method you are using..

Answer (score 6):

First thing. How are you handling Save Button; `Server Side` event or `Client Side`.

If you are using client side then use `Callback` server side event to save data and `End Callback` client event to close popup.

If using Server Side event then use `ASPxPopupControl.ShowOnPageLoad` Property.

```
protected void btnShowPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            txtPopup.Text = txtMain.Text;
            ASPxPopupControl1.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
        }
        protected void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // TODO: your code is here to process the popup window's data at the server
            txtMain.Text = txtPopup.Text;
            ASPxPopupControl1.ShowOnPageLoad = false;
        }
```

Refer following links for information:
[How to show the ASPxPopupControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E55.aspx)
[How to show and hide a popup window via server side code](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E499.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but not Worked for me unfortunately. I found a way and I'll write it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way for that as DevSupport mentioned. You must be write a java script like below:

```
//This function will close the pop window
function ClosePopWindow() {
     var paentWin = window.parent;
     window.parent.PopWindow.Hide();
}
```

And

```
//This function will clear inside content of pop window
function ClearPopWindow() {
        var paentWin = window.parent;
        paentWin.PopWindow.SetContentHtml(null);            
   }
```

and then call it from code behind when you need (after all of process you want to do) like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", "ClosePopWindow();", true);
```

or if you want to clear content you can use second function. Attention the `PopWindow` is `ClientInstanceName` of `ASPxPopupControl`. This approach will work in any situation for example when pop window defined in Master page and content URL is a window without master page because it try to get parent window in final html elements in browser.

You can read a Dev Support answer at this: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B199294

And from ASP.NET Forums, Terry Guo answer at this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1990775.aspx?How+to+close+the+popup+from+the+popup+containing+page+

Hope this help.